# Multiple Images in One LI in HTML

Tags: html, css, image, html-lists

I want this code to show as the two images being on top of each other. Outside li, it works, like the two images are on top of each other. But when I put it inside the li, it doesn't work anymore. Only the itemframe image appears but the 0 img doesn't appear. Please help. I need to use li because I am currently using a jquery file known as Sly. By the way the code for this is such

```css
img.shopitemframe{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

img.itemicon{
    position: relative;
    width: 75%;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<li>
    <img class="shopitemframe" src="Images/itemframe.jpg">
    <img class="itemicon" src="Images/Items/0.png">
</li>
```

Any tips or answers on how to make this work? Thank you for your time reading this question too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments in comments.

[W3Schools on `position` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

```css
li {
    position: relative; 
    /* It won't move but any descendant it has will be placed relative to its position. */
}

img.shopitemframe {
    width: 100%;
}

img.itemicon {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    /* Its `absolute` position will be calculated relative to `li` element position. 
       Check the link to W3Schools for more information on that. */
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 1; /* So it is on top of `.shopitemframe` */
}
```

```html
<li>
    <img class="shopitemframe" src="http://i.4cdn.org/c/1458667272301.png">
    <img class="itemicon" src="http://i.4cdn.org/c/1459478128149.gif">
</li>
```

Comment: I'm currently studying this code. Trying to change my code to having the same format as this. But still to no avail... But will continue to try.

Comment: @BengeminUy If you do not understand this code I strongly suggest, studying W3Schools link in first place :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @BengeminUy Oh, okey. Glad if I could actually help. Enjoy (:

Answer (score 0):

```js
    li
    {
      background-color: "#f00";
      width: 100%;
    }   

    img.shopitemframe{
        display: block;
    }
    
    img.itemicon{
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<ul><li>
    <img class="shopitemframe" src="http://placehold.it/300x200" />
    <img class="itemicon" src="http://placehold.it/300x200" />
</li>
  </ul>
```

Please check this code now.

Comment: But what exactly does display: block do?

Comment: @BengeminUy images are by default shown in a line unlike block elements which start on new line e.g. div, h1 etc. setting display: block, changes this behaviour and images start behaving like block elements.

Comment: I see thank you for that enlightenment. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

### Try This: change the Position to absolute

```css
img.shopitemframe{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

img.itemicon{
    position: absolute;
    width: 75%;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
 <li>
   <img class="shopitemframe" src="Images/itemframe.jpg">
   <img class="itemicon" src="Images/Items/0.png">
  </li>
```

---